# Highchart xaxis date displayed in number format issue

Tags: date, highcharts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9GHw.png)

Highcharts problem while rendering the date in xaxis highcharts converts the date to number formats.

Tried with below code but dint work:

"xAxis": [
     {
     "type": "datetime",
    "labels": {
     "format": "{value:%Y-%m-%d}" 
    } 
    } 
    ],

Comment: What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the entirety of your app code, but most probably trying to set the `plotOptions.series.cropThreshold` equal to value greater than your points amount, would fix the problem. For example:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    cropThreshold: 1000
  }
}
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.cropThreshold

Comment: Enjoy, and please mark the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers